# Divide Notation for Sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the book "Abstract Alegbra" by Dummit and Foote, on page 260, problem 41c states:

```
An ideal Q of R is primary iff every zero divisor in 
    R/Q is a nilpotent element of R/Q.
```

What does the `R/Q` notation stand for? I have seen it used with other sets, and cannot seem to find an answer online.

Comment: The book will explain it. Also, please see the Wikipedia article on [quotient rings.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the quotient set, or in this case the quotient ring.

If $E$ is an equivalence relation on $X$ then $X/E$ is the set of equivalence classes. In this context (and others like it) $R$ is a ring and $Q$ is an ideal which induces an equivalence relation on $R$. Therefore $R/Q$ is the set of equivalence classes from that induces relation, and it turns out that the operations of $R$ sort of "translate" naturally to make $R/Q$ a ring as well, which is called the quotient ring.

Comment: Thanks! Would that be the same for, say, `C/N` where `C` = the complex numbers, and `N` = the natural numbers?

Comment: That would greatly depend on the context.